# I encountered a black screen error when I updated in Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04, nvidia

I am using ubuntu 18.04. I have a dual screencard available, I am using nvidia: geforce gtx 1050. When I ran nvidia-smi on my computer, 'NVIDIA-SMI failed because it could not communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure you have the latest NVIDIA driver installed and running. I've tried some things. I've tried so many things that I don't remember what I tried last. When I reboot after updating it, a black screen comes out, a constantly flashing screen please help.

Comment: Translated from Turkish. This is an English only site.

Comment: I've tried so many things that I don't remember what I tried last. If you can not detail what you tried no one can help you, we do not know what you dd.

Comment: Bu sorunu recovery mode ile  bozuk paketleri onar diyerek sorunu hallettim. Teşekkür ederim